# how to pass values using POST method in createURL

Tags: php, yii

I have this script that will open a new tab for PDF creation of a report.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> window.open("'.$this->createUrl('createXls', array('val'=>$val)).'");</script>';
```

As of now the values passed are via GET method. What code will I use to make it pass values via POST?

Comment: You can't use just URLs to post.  You need a form.

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because the poster is simply asking for code/a solution without demonstrating any effort to solve the issue themselves

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hidden html form, then assign your url to form's action. after that put a input hidden type in the form with your desired value. and finally submit the form with jquery. Now you can access that variable via POST int the form action!